# Decorator: Maintain state

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I need to compose information regarding the given information like what parameter the given function takes etc. The example what I would like to do is

```
@author("Joey")
@parameter("name", type=str)
@parameter("id", type=int)
@returns("Employee", desc="Returns employee with given details", type="Employee")
def get_employee(name, id):
     //
     // Some logic to return employee
     //
```

Skeleton of decorator could be as follows:

```
json = {}
def author(author):
    def wrapper(func):
         def internal(*args, **kwargs):
              json["author"] = name
              func(args, kwargs)
         return internal 
    return wrapepr
```

Similarly, parameter decorator could be written as follows:

```
def parameter(name, type=None):
    def wrapper(func):
         def internal(*args, **kwargs):
              para = {}
              para["name"] = name
              para["type"] = type
              json["parameters"].append = para
              func(args, kwargs)
         return internal 
    return wrapepr
```

Similarly, other handlers could be written. At the end, I can just call one function which would get all formed JSONs for each function.

End output could be

```
[
{fun_name, "get_employee", author: "Joey", parameters : [{para_name : Name, type: str}, ... ], returns: {type: Employee, desc: "..."}
{fun_name, "search_employee", author: "Bob", parameters : [{para_name : age, type: int}, ... ], returns: {type: Employee, desc: "..."}
... 
}
]
```

I'm not sure how I can maintain the state and know to consolidate the data regarding one function should be handled together.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully get your use case, but wouldn't it work to add author to your current functions as:

```
func_list = []

def func(var):
     return var

json = {}
json['author'] = 'JohanL'
json['func'] = func.func_name
func.json = json

func_list.append(func.json)

def func2(var):
     return var

json = {}
json['author'] = 'Ganesh'
func2.json = json

func_list.append(func2.json)
```

This can be automated using a decorator as follows:

```
def author(author):
    json = {}
    def author_decorator(func):
        json['func'] = func.func_name
        json['author'] = author
        func.json = json
        return func
    return author_decorator

def append(func_list):
    def append_decorator(func):
        func_list.append(func.json)
        return func
    return append_decorator

func_list = []

@append(func_list)
@author('JohanL')
def func(var):
     return var

@append(func_list)
@author('Ganesh')
def func2(var):
     return var
```

Then you can access the `json` dict as `func.json` and `func2.json` or find the functions in the func_list. Note that for the decorators to work, you have to add them in the order I have put them and I have not added any error handling.

Also, if you prefer the func_list to not be explicitly passed, but instead use a globaly defined list with an explicit name, the code can be somewhat simplified to:

```
func_list = []

def author(author):
    json = {}
    def author_decorator(func):
        json['func'] = func.func_name
        json['author'] = author
        func.json = json
        return func
    return author_decorator

def append(func):
    global func_list
    func_list.append(func.json)
    return func

@append
@author('JohanL')
def func(var):
     return var

@append
@author('Ganesh')
def func2(var):
     return var
```

Maybe this is sufficient for you?

Comment: A problem will occur when there is another `func2` with author `Ganesh`. We need to create output `[{func: 'func', author: "JohanL"}, {func: "func2", author: "Ganesh."}]`

Will the approach work for second function?

Comment: This will work for both your functions as I show in my updated example. There will be a unique json dict for each.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @JohanL. 
Yes. The two JSONs are generated as per the JSON. But final output is a list of all such JSON. For that we need to create another decorator, right? And that decorator needs to be called only after the first decorator?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a second decorator, that appends the functions to a func_list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is good but can this be automated without passing the parameter `func_list` explicitly. I'm trying to make this as a library and users shouldn't need to pass the parameters explicitly.

Comment: Well, you need some kind of global storage, but sure, this can be automated, so that the `func_list` is not explicitly passed. The simplest way would be to just not pass func_list but use the global copy. I will add that to my answer.